# Appium: custom android app keeps crashing on launch

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

Have a problem where all of a sudden a previously working appium based android app selenium test has stopped working as it did (consistently successful).

The issue is specifically to do with the launch of the app by appium (the app always launches when opened with physical user input..). Basically the app launches, the loading screen appears and then it crashes. This happens most of the time but not always. I've found it usually works fine initially after restarting the phone. However, it'll crash on subsequent runs.

Any assistance would be much appreciated. Tried many things/searching online already but it's all been to of no avail..

Here's the appium output:

```
[AndroidDriver] Parsed pid: '27608' pkg: 'com.dedsert.betbright.uat' from
[AndroidDriver]     USER      PID   PPID  VSIZE  RSS   WCHAN              PC  NAME
[AndroidDriver]     u0_a236   27608 4736  3621124 393160          0 0000000000 R com.dedsert.betbright.uat
[AndroidDriver] Returning process name: 'com.dedsert.betbright.uat'
[AndroidDriver] Found webviews: ["WEBVIEW_com.dedsert.betbright.uat"]
[AndroidDriver] Available contexts: ["NATIVE_APP","WEBVIEW_com.dedsert.betbright.uat"]
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.setContext() result: null
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a9457315-d657-4fd1-bdf0-36fe5d76b3c5/context 200 245 ms - 76 
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: shortMsg=java.lang.StackOverflowError
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_RESULT: longMsg=stack size 1037KB
[AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_CODE: 0
[UiAutomator] UiAutomator exited unexpectedly with code 4294967295, signal null
[UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[AndroidDriver] Shutting down Android driver
[Appium] Closing session, cause was 'UiAUtomator shut down unexpectedly'
[Appium] Removing session a9457315-d657-4fd1-bdf0-36fe5d76b3c5 from our master session list
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\kroring\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce051715c336451002","shell","am","force-stop","com.dedsert.betbright.uat"]
[ADB] Pressing the HOME button
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\kroring\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce051715c336451002","shell","input","keyevent",3]
[AndroidBootstrap] Cannot shut down Android bootstrap; it has already shut down
[Logcat] Stopping logcat capture
[ADB] Getting connected devices...
[ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[ADB] Running 'C:\Users\kroring\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe' with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","ce051715c336451002","shell","am","force-stop","io.appium.unlock"]
[AndroidDriver] Not cleaning generated files. Add `clearSystemFiles` capability if wanted.
[HTTP] --> POST /wd/hub/session/a9457315-d657-4fd1-bdf0-36fe5d76b3c5/context {"name":"WEBVIEW_com.dedsert.betbright.uat"}
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session/a9457315-d657-4fd1-bdf0-36fe5d76b3c5/context 404 1 ms - 131
```

Not a whole lot to be seen on the IntelliJ side - did spot this in the stacktrace given:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: A session is either terminated or not started (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 5 milliseconds
```

Comment: `shortMsg=java.lang.StackOverflowError` looks like a process is running out of memory. This could be an indication of a memory leak in one of the programs but it's hard to tell with the limited information and knowledge about your setup. Are there a lot of apps/notifications/services/background processes running on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall appium and reinstall appium and it will work for you.
From command line.

```
npm uninstall -g appium
```

Reinstall the appium.

```
npm install -g appium
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your phone is out of memory. It could be worthwhile to clear the cache of your testing phone :

- Power off your device. This method is different for different
  manufacturers, and you should look it up on the internet before
  proceeding further.
- Load into your bootloader screen by holding down
  a combination of keys. In some devices, you have to press the Power
  button with Volume down key simultaneously. In other devices, Power
  button with both the Volume keys have to pressed simultaneously.
  Touchscreen might not work, and you have to navigate using Volume
  keys.
- Go to Recovery and select it with a tap on the Power button.
- Go to Wipe cache partition and tap the Power button to select it.
- After the cache gets cleared, select Reboot system now.

Information from (step 4): https://fossbytes.com/clear-android-cache-data-quick-methods/